# Select data, derived from a join of two other tables, into a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I manage a scientific database that can use both MS Access and SQL Server. I wish to select data into a third table from a select query joining two tables in the database.  The following query works for Access but fails for SQL Server. Can anyone suggest a solution? Note that I do not wish to select duplicates so have used a LEFT JOIN and a RIGHT JOIN, rather than a FULL OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT *
INTO AA
FROM (
    SELECT P.Well, P.Type, P.Depth, P.Temperature, S.Rotation
    FROM PT P 
    LEFT JOIN SPIN S 
        ON S.Well = P.Well AND S.Depth = P.Depth 
    WHERE P.Type = 'PT-S' 
    UNION 
    SELECT S.Well, S.Type, S.Depth, P.Temperature, S.Rotation 
    FROM PT P 
    RIGHT JOIN SPIN S 
        ON S.[Well] = P.[Well] AND S.Depth = P.Depth 
    WHERE S.Type = 'SPIN-PT'
)
```

Comment: "but fails for SQL Server" what does this mean? Syntax error? Returns the wrong data?

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO AAA SELECT...`. The syntax you're using creates a new table with the results, it's not for inserting in to an existing table. Also, saying something fails without giving error messages, etc, is like asking a mechanic to fix your car while blindfolded.

Comment: I wish to create a new temporary table as I need to later modify the results, and I find it easier to use temporary tables than a multi-layered single query.  Speed is not really an issue, The error reported by SQL Server is: Incorrect syntax near ')'.  I trust this helps.

Comment: In SQL Server a temp table starts with `#` so you would want `#AA` but I can't comment on MS Access.

Comment: I should mention that the query between the brackets returns the correct results for both Access and SQL Server.  The extra line `SELECT * INTO AA FROM' is causing the problem.

Comment: Oh, you need a derived table alias in SQL Server e.g. `) as T`

Comment: I manage temporary tables in SQL Server as in Access, by joining the user's login to the table name to make them unique and avoid clashes over the network, and then manually deleting them when not in use. I will not use the alias anywhere in the code, but should the alias have a unique value?

Answer (score 1):

you should name your query like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO AA
FROM (
    SELECT P.Well, P.Type, P.Depth, P.Temperature, S.Rotation
    FROM PT P 
    LEFT JOIN SPIN S ON S.Well = P.Well AND S.Depth = P.Depth 
    WHERE P.Type = 'PT-S' 
    
    UNION 

    SELECT S.Well, S.Type, S.Depth, P.Temperature, S.Rotation 
    FROM PT P 
    RIGHT JOIN SPIN S ON S.[Well] = P.[Well] AND S.Depth = P.Depth 
    WHERE S.Type = 'SPIN-PT'
) As QueryName
```